# Question about lie bracket..

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $\mathfrak{h}\subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ be a Lie subalgebra. Write $F_p=DR_p(e)\mathfrak{h}$, $p\in G$, where $R_p:G\rightarrow G$ given by $a\mapsto ap$ is the right translation. Suppose $X, Y\in \mathfrak{X}(G)$ are smooth fields and $$X(p), Y(p)\in F_p,$$ for all $p\in G$. With this hypothesis I can conclude $[X(e), Y(e)]\in \mathfrak{h}=F_e$. Does this imply $[X(p), Y(p)]\in F_p$ for all $p\in G$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know $$[f_*X\ f_*Y]=f_*{[X\ Y]}$$ here $f_*$ denote $f$ tangent map. general speaking,$f$ is diffeomorphism.
then this question is obvious.
$$X(p)=DR_p(e)X_1\    X_1\in h$$
$$Y(p)=DR_p(e)X_1\    X_2\in h$$
 \begin{eqnarray*}
% \nonumber to remove numbering (before each equation)
  [X(p)\ Y(p)] &=& [DR_p X_1\ DR_p X_2 ]\\
   &=& DR_p [X_1\  X_2 ]\in DR_p(h)=F_p \ \forall p\in G
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I had got to that conclusion too =D Thanks anyway..